# Hidden message in musical notes

Tags: cipher, visual, knowledge, steganography, music

Can you find it? The message might be a self-fulfilling prophecy

[image]

Here's a hint:

> [image]

Original hint:

> The musical notes are related to the squares they touch

Comment: Hints please? :D

Comment: I thought of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRTdq0VsLGQ but it doesn't seem to be a fit

Comment: It would already be puzzling enough to figure out the correct names of those two violet colors :-)

Comment: names or hex codes? :|>

Comment: The hex codes should be (left to right, top to bottom) #168645, #e840ee, #9e8cdf, #f6f647, #40cac2, #8c86de.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we extract the hexcodes of the colors:

> #168645, #e840ee, #9e8cdf
>  #f6f647, #40cac2, #8c86de

---

As it turns out, each hexcode has an operation applied to them:

> Leftmost notes are reversed, so we unreverse them:
>  168645 -> 54 68 61
>  f6f647 -> 74 6f 6f

---

> Middle notes are doubled in length, so we halve the hex values (it helps that the digits are all even)
>  e840ee -> 74 20 77
>  40cac2 -> 20 65 61

---

> Right notes are inverted in colors, so we take the complement of the numbers:
>  9e8cdf -> 61 73 20
>  8c86de -> 73 79 21

---

Finally we convert using ASCII:

> ```
> T h a | t   w | a s
>
> t o o |   e a | s y !
> ```
>
> Or more readably, **That was too easy!**

---

For completion's sake, the hint explained:

> Once again the hint had its colors inverted. Take the hexcodes and take their complements:
>  9edf97 -> 61 20 68
>  96918b -> 69 6e 74
>  Or, converted from ASCII: **a hint**

Comment: Nicely done! And the hint? :)